# get_posts not working as expected

Tags: get-posts

I'm trying to get posts from 3 different categories and list them on the front page:

```
  // Carousel articles
  $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'orderby' => 'date', 'category' => 'karusell' );
  $carousel = get_posts($args);

  // News articles
  $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'orderby' => 'date', 'category' => 'nyheter' );
  $news = get_posts($args);

  // Featured articles - max 2 posts
  $args = array( 'numberposts' => 2, 'orderby' => 'date', 'category' => 'feature' );
  $featured_posts = get_posts($args);
```

Then I output them by doing this:

```
foreach( $carousel as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
 // code here
endforeach;
```

My problem is that all my loops outputs the same posts. Am I using the wrong function for getting posts?

I could use something like this:

```
query_posts("category_name=feature&posts_per_page=2&orderby=date");
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
//code
endwhile;
```

But I was hoping I could fetch all the articles at the top of my code and not "inline".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `get_posts()`, try using the category ID instead of the category slug.

For example:

```
// Carousel articles
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'orderby' => 'date', 'category' => 1 );
$carousel = get_posts($args);

// News articles  
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'orderby' => 'date', 'category' => 2 );
$news = get_posts($args);

// Featured articles - max 2 posts
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 2, 'orderby' => 'date', 'category' => 3 );
$featured_posts = get_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',        
    'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'karusell'
    )
));
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```